# How to convert a html page to docx in .net 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0, docx

I need to convert and download my html page as word(.docx) document.
I am able to convert to doc format. But conversion to docx format is getting corrupted file.

My Code is

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Newdoc.doc");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Write("<html><head></head><body>");
Response.Write("My html data");
Response.Write("</body></html>");
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

Comment: I dont' see where the converting is happening in your code... Which library are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

This project spire.doc enables you to convert html page to word(.docx) without corrupting file, it supports Word 97-2003, Word 2007 and Word 2010.

Answer (score -1):

docx4j can [convert XHTML to docx](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML).

That's Java, but you can IKVM it.

Comment: is there any dll available for .net 2.0 with C#

Comment: Yes, see further http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/c-net-import-xhtml-into-docx-without-word/